# NullPointerException while adding data to the database from online page

Tags: java, websphere, translation, nullpointerexception, rollback

I am getting a NullPointerException Exception while adding data from the online JSP page.

The error description is as follows:

```
javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: CORBA
TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK 0x0 No; nested exception is:
org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:
javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: ; nested exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No
```

I am using Websphere server "IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND, 6.0.2.35".

However, there was no problem when i was using "IBM WebSphere Application Server - ND, 6.0.2.17"

Is there any idea why this is happending.

Appreaciate all your efforts in this regard.

Thanks,
Manoja.

Comment: You need to post the full stack trace that shows the code that's triggering the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the NPE occurs in an EJB called when processing entered data.

In SystemOut/Err log, there likely will be complete stacktrace of the error. Find the nested NPE there and check its stacktrace for classes that belong to your application (i.e. no IBM or Java ones). That should  give you some clue at least.